# Refreshing of data is not happening properly

Tags: javascript

I have 1 user under which 3 services are there, without logging, if I am trying to open ui again I have an option to login with a different user.

After clicking i am able to login as a second user but data is showing for the 1st user.

It is not refreshing properly even after sign in as a different user.
Below is the piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    if (localStorage.getItem("AG_SP_USER_TEMP") != null ) {
    localStorage.setItem("AG_SP_USER",localStorage.getItem("AG_SP_USER_TEMP"));
    localStorage.removeItem("AG_SP_USER_TEMP");
    }
 </script>
```

Here, based on the user we are getting data then removing .
Can you please tell what supposed to do so that refresh happens properly.

Comment: It look like you save locally in the browser cache, but you save the AG_SP_USER_TEMP over AG_SP_USER when you log as AG_SP_USER_TEMP, so on user change you have the same data, even you remove the AG_SP_USER_TEMP user from local storage.

Comment: Then what supposed to do as if i tried removing AG_SP_USER before AG_SP_USER_TEMP : then link to change the user is not only coming up.

Comment: If the client browser is shared through users, you should not save user infos there, for obvious security concerns. In this case, you should just save the info of one user with the proper key. I think you don't have the user infos in the local cache (first login?), you should load from server and then store locally.